# how to add html in httpmodule?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add html in httpmodule.
Can i add controls directly in httpmodule?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add controls in HttpModule but you can modify the output. Get the current context using `HttpContext.Current` and use the Response property to modify the response.

Comment: Can i change response Application_EndRequest();

Comment: Yes - you may use EndRequest but perhaps better option would be `PostRequestHandlerExecute` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postrequesthandlerexecute.aspx) depending upon your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but maybe you could add them once asp.net has mapped the request to an handler something like

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.PostMapRequestHandler += new EventHandler(context_PostMapRequestHandler);
}

void context_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
   Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
}
```

After that you can hook on to the page events and modify the content

Comment: i want to add lable to text in Application_EndRequest()?

Comment: this won't work - issue is that there is no reliable way for module to know if control tree has been created, view-state has been loaded, post-back events have been handled etc (assuming that the current handler is a page). If module has to hook page events then it must make sure to release those event handlers! In general, a base page would be better option rather than going via http module for such requirement!